# Merging the results of two GET Rest APIs into a single JSON list

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest

I am currently stuck on trying to merge two JSON lists from two GET REST API calls.

The first API call grabs the userID of the person trying to access the webpage.

The second two urls each return a list of userIDs who are in a specific security group. 
I need to have a list that merges the values of both JSON lists into a single list.

If the userID that is accessing the webpage is not in the list of UserIDs in **either** security group, then the page content is hidden from them. The user needs to be in only one of the two security groups to have access to the webpage.

What I've tried so far makes it to where the user needs to be in **both** security groups to have access, when they really need to only be in **one**. I could be going about this the wrong way. Could this be turned into an if elseif statement? Any ideas?

```
var submitterId = null;
    var userIdUrl = '/api/HttpCurrentUser';
    var Url1 = '/api/ActiveDirectoryMembers/example1';
    var Url2 = '/api/ActiveDirectoryMembers/example2';
    $("#masterContainer").hide();
    $.get(userIdUrl).done(function (result) {
        submitterId = result;
        isInGroup = false;
        $.get(Url1).done(function (result) {
            result.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item == submitterId) {
                    $("#masterContainer").show();
                    isInGroup = true;
                }
            });
            if (!isInGroup) {
                $("#masterContainer").replaceWith("Access to this site is restricted to the example1 and example2 groups);
            }
        });
        $.get(Url2).done(function (result) {
            result.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item == submitterId) {
                    $("#masterContainer").show();
                    isInGroup = true;
                }
            });
            if (!isInGroup) {
                $("#masterContainer").replaceWith("Access to this site is restricted to example 1 and example 2 groups");
            }
        });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code and, added comments on the edits:

```
var submitterId = null;
    var userIdUrl = '/api/HttpCurrentUser';
    var Url1 = '/api/ActiveDirectoryMembers/example1';
    var Url2 = '/api/ActiveDirectoryMembers/example2';
    var mergedResult; // a variable to hold both results
    $("#masterContainer").hide();
    $.get(userIdUrl).done(function (result) {
      submitterId = result;
      isInGroup = false;
      $.get(Url1).done(function (result) {
        mergedResult = result;
      });
      $.get(Url2).done(function (result) {
        $.extend(mergedResult, result); // will merge the result, into mergedResult (the first target)
      });

      mergedResult.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item == submitterId) {
          $("#masterContainer").show();
          isInGroup = true;
        }
      });

      if (!isInGroup) {
        $("#masterContainer").replaceWith("Access to this site is restricted to example 1 and example 2 groups");
      }

    });
```

Basically, use [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge the results.

Comment: I am getting an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' at mergedResult.forEach(function (item){}

Comment: @AngelaDylan what is the result you get when you console.log(mergedResult)? Pass the result from Url1 and Url2 like: result.json().

Comment: I get an array of 218 ids returned

Comment: @AngelaDylan strange, you should be able to loop though the array using `forEach`. Any possibility in post the response or a structure of the json that Url1 is returning?

Comment: @AngelaDylan if the response is an array type, use `$.merge` instead of `$.extend`. [merge](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

Comment: An Example of what the JSON looks like: ["123456", "980281"] that is if i use IE to run the api call, if i use Chrome it returns <ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>1920198</string>
<string>9870057</string>
<string>0980014</string></ArrayOfstring>

Comment: I changed the $.extend. to $merge and i still get the same error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. Is foreach allowed in Jquery? or should i use a .each? or maybe for(var i=0; i <mergedResult.length; i++){  if (item == submitterId) {
                $("#masterContainer").show();
                isInGroup = true;
            }